# Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on Django. I use PostgreSQL database.

**Full error says:**

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check your postgresql server setting.

Comment: I have installed PostgreSQL on my machine. Still service is not starting... any idea??

Answer (score 18):

Wild stab in the dark: You're on a machine with an IPv6 resolver where `localhost` defaults to the IPv6 address `::1`, but `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` is set to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` not `*` or you're using an older PostgreSQL built with a C library that doesn't have transparent IPv6 support.

Change `listen_addresses` to `localhost` and make sure `localhost` resolves to both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, or set it to `::1, 127.0.0.1` to explicitly specify both IPv4 and IPv6. Or just set it to `*` to listen on all interfaces.  Alternately, if you don't care about IPv6, connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

See [this Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22Is+the+server+running+on+host+%E2%80%9Clocalhost%E2%80%9D+(%3A%3A1)+and+accepting+TCP%2FIP+connections+on+port+5432%3F%22) or [this Stack Overflow search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Is+the+server+running+on+host+%E2%80%9Clocalhost%E2%80%9D+%28%3A%3A1%29+and+accepting+TCP%2FIP+connections+on+port+5432%3F%22) for more information.

(Posting despite my close-vote because I voted the question for migration).

Comment: it's been a while but I got same error and fixed it by changing my listen port to 5432 (was 5433) in postgresql.conf, but what if I want to keep my 5433 in conf??

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Specify the port to the client when you connect instead.