# Enable remote access to Postgre 9.2 in ubuntu?

Tags: qt, postgresql, remote-access, postgresql-9.2, tcp

I can't access remotely my postgre database. My fellow is making a QT project that access the database from my web-server. It's very close to the problem from this guy: [Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648677/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections)

And with some research in google, all solutions point to set the listen_addresses property in postgresql.conf like  this:
listen_addresses = '*'

and in pg_hba.conf add this line in the IPV4 connections

host    all     all 0.0.0.0/0   trust

I've already done it, and also have created an exception in ufw
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       x.x.x.x.x

when x.x.x.x is the ip I want to give access.

I've also tried some variants to the configuration above ,like
listen_addresses = 'localhost, x.x.x.x'
and
host    all     all x.x.x.x/32  md5

Comment: Have you uncommented and set the line `listening_address` in `postgresql.conf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message of the linked question happens only when trying to connect locally. That's what *...running on host **localhost**...* means.

When connecting to a remote host, the client doesn't set `localhost` in the host field, but the IP address or name of the remote machine (well, unless using a SSH tunnel but it's not mentioned here).

Otherwise please indicate the exact connection parameters of the client and the exact error message.