# Postgres server refused connection

Tags: postgresql

Maybe this Question repeat but I am not getting any solution I am using centos 7 and Postgres 9.3.
While connecting the PostgreSQL server it through error,

Error

> Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1)
>   and         accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432

Even I set   pg_hba.config file but still I am getting the same error 
I tried to remove `postmaster.pid` but I got an error `no such file and no pid exist` 
Please tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved this with the explanation:

"Wild stab in the dark: You're on a machine with an `IPv6` resolver where `localhost` defaults to the IPv6 address `::1`, but listen_addresses in `postgresql.conf` is set to `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` not `*` or you're using an older PostgreSQL built with a C library that doesn't have transparent `IPv6` support.

Change `listen_addresses` to `localhost` and make sure `localhost` resolves to both the `IPv4` and `IPv6` addresses, or set it to `::1`, `127.0.0.1` to explicitly specify both `IPv4` and `IPv6`. Or just set it to `*` to listen on all interfaces. Alternately, if you don't care about `IPv6`, connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of  `localhost`."

Reference link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648677/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections).

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused) `post` can help you too.

Comment: Please, check if is the same port of your database.yml, by default on my postgresql-9.2 use 5433 instead 5432, don't forget to restart the postgres server, good luck

Comment: If dont work, see my edit, this error can be solved with variable forms, depends on what can be

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether firewall allow connection on that port.
If on Ubuntu command `sudo ufw status`
the result wil be like this

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
```

You can see that port 5432 is not allowed.
Now run command `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp` and
check ufw status
`sudo ufw status` will now return

```
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
```

If this doesn't work you may probably haven't allowed IP to listen to postgres.
Change `listen_address = 'localhost'` to  `listen_address = '*'`
in **postgres.conf** file.